# nextFocusForward to a disbled EditText creating problem

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I have multiple EditText in Android XML view, which contains a sequence of "nextFocusForward" for focusing to the next EditText for inputs from keyboard, now I have a condition in which some EditText is disabled now, the sequence of the EditText focus from keyboard next is blocking anywhere, is there any way we can go to the next input if the requesting focus EditText is disabled ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your condition when you set an `EditText` as disabled, set it also to not focusable. This way, the `EditText` will be ignored and the next one will be focused.

```
editText.setFocusable(false);
```

Remember to set it to `true` if you enable it again!